# Drawing extruded 3D lines with arrowheads in Three.js

Tags: three.js

I'm very new to Three.js and I'm trying to create an app where the user can draw 3D lines (continuous, dashed, dotted) including arrowheads, similar to MS PowerPoint lines and curves functionality.

I've used THREE.TubeGeometry (https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_extrude_splines) and looks like a possible solution, but needs a lot of work to get what I want.

Before I start trying to reinvent the wheel during months, I would like to know if there is some class or module that already does this in Three.js, or what's the best way to achieve it.

Comment: You have in the world of webGL Babylon.js, PlayCanvas, Processing.js, p5.js, NextCharts, GraphicsJS ... for example here a project in 3d for Ecommerce i did here just a little try using three.js http://modulotheque.com/config3D/index2.html

Comment: Based on its name, [`THREE.ArrowHelper`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/helpers/ArrowHelper) isn't meant to be a full solution for anything (I only use it for debugging), but you could use it as a basis for your own solution.

Comment: you've probably already seen this example, but it sounds like you want something like this: [https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_spline_editor](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_spline_editor)

Comment: Thanks all for your comments. They are really helpful to make sure I'm in the 'right path' :)

@headmax, thanks for input. After comparing Babylon, PlayCanvas and ThreeJS, this last one was my choice.

Comment: @TheJim01 yes, ArrowHelper styles would be perfect if there were an extruded spline version. I need to investigate if this code can be adapted somehow to extruded spline.

Comment: @micnil thanks, that demo is very similar to what I want to achieve, but with extruded lines, so they have a feeling of depth.